# Fluid not appearing in object mode or game "play" mode

Tags: 3d-view, fluid-simulation

Why does the fluids in my model only appear when I press render? I see video's where the person who's recording can see his fluid in object mode. But I only get to see the object that's supposed to be the fluid.

Comment: Fluid is not supported in game mode

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise and in other modes then?

Comment: Blender Internal and Cycles do support it

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise and how can I see fluids in edit mode then?